# Deleting rows that contain a keyword in the column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, microsoft-excel-2013

I have an excel file that has a id as one of the columns, each id has multiple entries and follow a set of survey questions. I need to delete all of the rows that have that keyword (which is in a seperate column) and that are associated to that ID number. How do I do that either through conditional formatting, VBA, or C#?

Comment: I was able to find a vba script wherein I deleted all other values that dont have that keyword. Now how would i take the IDs that have that keyword and delete those entries from the master workbook? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would use the Power Query Add-In for this.  You can load data from an Excel Table into a Query.

I would start by building one Query that filters down to just the rows that need to be deleted. Then I would start another Query based on the same Excel Table. With this one I would Merge the first Query, joining by ID Number and adding any column from the first Query.  Then I would Filter out all the non-blank values in that column.